# sql join two tables by one column values not in another table's coumn

Tags: sql, presto

I would like to join two tables on presto db.

Tab1:

```
user_id.   val1. (array of string)
'abh'      ['568']
'yvg'      ['901']
```

tab2:

```
user_id.  vals. (array of string)
'abh'.    ['568', '710', '281']
'yvg'     ['115', '207']
```

The expected result:

```
user_id.   val1.    vals
'yvg'      ['901']  ['115', '207']
```

because '901' not in vals of 'yvg' in tab2.

my sql:

```
 select t1.user_id, t1.val1, t2.vals
 from tab1 as t1
 join tab2 as t2
 on t1.user_id=t2.user_id
 and t1.val1 not in t2.vals
```

but, it does not work.
How to add the filtering condition in the sql query ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Arrays generally need specialized functions to do what you want.

See the [`arrays_overlap`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html?highlight=array_intersect#arrays_overlap) documentation.

I've also commented out a `contains` method, if you're certain that `val1` is always a single value.

```
select t1.user_id, t1.val1, t2.vals
from tab1 as t1
join tab2 as t2
on t1.user_id=t2.user_id
and not arrays_overlap(t2.vals, t1.val1)
```

Working example:

```
SELECT tab1.user_id, val1, vals
FROM (VALUES ('abh', ARRAY['568']),
             ('yvg', ARRAY['901'])) AS tab1(user_id, val1)
JOIN (VALUES ('abh', ARRAY['568', '710', '281']),
             ('yvg', ARRAY['115', '207'])) AS tab2(user_id, vals)
    ON tab1.user_id = tab2.user_id
           AND NOT arrays_overlap(vals, val1)
        -- AND NOT contains(vals, val1[1])
```

Output:

| user_id | val1 | vals |
| --- | --- | --- |
| yvg | {901} | {115,207} |